# Integrity constraint violation error message with Laravel 5.2.45

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am following a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atWUeGBIAAM) about Laravel but when I change this line:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

to:

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

in UserController.php I get this error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null (SQL: insert
>   into `users` (`email`, `first_name`, `password`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (, ,
>   y$WNp1qKLTDNktowIC0LRKE.SjCOxm8wZV97BRCLAcPk3wsmGR9mJvG, 2017-07-09
>   20:09:52, 2017-07-09 20:09:52))

This is the whole function:

```
public function postSignUp(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request['email'];
    $first_name = $request['first_name'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->first_name = $first_name;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->save();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    //return redirect()->back();  }
```

I tried `$email = $request->input('email');` but nothing change.

Can any one give me an explanation and a solution?
oh and this is my signup form

```
<form  action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first_name">Your First name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Your Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
</form>
```

as i say it work perfectly with  `return redirect()->back();`

Comment: share your login form with routes as well

Comment: could you confirm that the request has value for email. try `dd($request['email'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that the problem is in my route file,i mixed

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [
'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
'as' => 'dashboard'
```

with

```
Route::post('/signup', [
'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
'as' => 'signup'
```

thanks every body

Answer (score 0):

Your `email` field on your request object is empty, be sure to confirm that the field has some value printing it with `dd($request->email)` or `dd($request->input('email')`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

Do this:

```
return redirect(route('dashboard'));
```

Might work.
I use the same version of the framework, and when I use the `redirect` code the way I put it, it always works.

I confess it would be easier if you shared your routes, but at first glance that's what I could recognize as different.